# Java Regex for Unicode or special character

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I have below statement in Javascript (NodeJS) -

```
const name = (name) =>
 name && !XRegExp('^[\\p{L}\'\\d][ \\p{L}\'\\d-]*[\\p{L}\'-\'\\d]$').test(name)
? 'Invalid' : undefined
```

This regex is for name can accept `.` , `-` and  (space) and should start with character.

How can I achieve same validation regex in java. I tried below -

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^(?U)[\\p{L}\\'\\d][ \\p{L}\\'\\d-]*[\\p{L}\\'-\\'\\d]$" , 
message="Invalid name")
String name;
```

Comment: In Java AFAIK, the unicode inline flag is `(?u)` not `(?U)`. Also, be carefull with the hyphen inside a character class, in particular `\\'-\\'` that seems to define a strange range of characters.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte "*`UNICODE_CASE` Unicode-aware case folding can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression (?u)*" and "*The `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression (?U).

The flag implies `UNICODE_CASE`, that is, it enables Unicode-aware case folding*"

Comment: `(?U)` is redundant unless `\d` must match Persian, Indic, etc. digits.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: Thanks you, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that maybe this expression might work, based on the one you have provided:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^[\\p{L}\\d'][ \\p{L}\\d'-]*[\\p{L}\\d'-]$";
final String string = "éééééé";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/RrT3Qy/1/)

Comment: Do you really need the `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag? Also note that `[\\p{L}\\d']` can also be written `[\\p{alnum}']` (one character more to write but it contains letters and digits).

Comment: @Emma, Thank You. I have one question why below statement giving me false 
`final String string = "West.-";` when I do `pattern.matcher(string).matches();` as this string is valid in my case.

Comment: @ppb Is `West.-` really valid - I can't see how the decimal point is being validated with posted regex, but I do not know Javascript?